# Default values for Preferred language, email format, email greeting, postal greeting and addressee

Tags: import, default-settings

we are in the process of setting up CiviCRM and we are importing a lot of records from a previous CRM. when we do the import, the preferred language defaults to english.  how do we get this to be a null value unless we import a value?

Same question for email format, email greeting, postal greeting and addressee.  All are showing a default value. Null would be more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

How do you import? Via csv upload?

If your import scenario is complex by any means I would strongly recommend to make use of the api. This approach helps you to get control over all aspects of field mapping.

Yours // nielo

Answer (score 0):

Since the default language is set in the db (but i am having trouble finding that in the UI) you could set it so there is no default.

in the db look for civicrm_option_value

filter for option_group_id = 75, find the one set to is_default = 1 and set it to 0

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old remark but you better could first look up the good option_group_id bij selecting it in option_group with name = 'languages'.

I don't believe this is working this way. With no inherit CMS-language (and single lingual) I get the default language is English - VS with on the screen 'Languages, Currency, Locations' the Default Language : Nederlands.